# How do I remove the dot at the end of each substring

Tags: regex, excel, vba

In trying to remove the dot at the end of each substring `A6.3., A6.5.` I came up with the following solution. However I get a run-time error "5017"

This is what I have

```
With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = "(?<=[1-9]\.[1-9])\."
    RemoveNumbers = .Replace("A6.3., A6.5. ", "")
End With

MsgBox RemoveNumbers
```

The outcome should be: `A6.3, A6.5`

Comment: You should test for a match first `If .Test("A6.3, A6.5.") Then`

Comment: Where from, such a "substring" comes? From an Excel range/cell? Is it a string which must be processed before inputting an Excel range?

Comment: Also, positive look behind is not supported in VBA which is what is causing the error as your pattern isn't valid. I think you could replace your pattern with simply `\.\B`

Comment: Thanks Tom, changing the regex to `\.\B` did the job. It seems that positive look behinds aren't supported.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove dot without regex:

```
Sub RemoveLastDot()
    myValues = Split("A6.3., A6.5.", ",")
    myRslt = ""
    myFirst = ""
    For Each myVal In myValues
        If InStrB(Trim(myVal), ".") = Len(Trim(myVal)) Then
           myRslt = myRslt & myFirst & Left(Trim(myVal), Len(Trim(myVal)) - 1)
           else
               myRslt = myRslt & myFirst & Trim(myVal)
        End If
        myFirst = ", "
    Next
    MsgBox myRslt
End Sub
```